# useLocation state is coming null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to debug my app. It's a simple app, where it takes random api images from spoonacular, then like tinder, you either press "Yah" or "Nah". When "Yah" is pressed, it pushes up to an array, and it is supposed to display that array in the Checkout component. I've been trying different methods but nothing worked. I used useLocation and it worked for a minute then the state turned null.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Home.css"

const userFood = [
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715544-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/645978-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716279-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/689453-556x370.jpg",
];


const Home = () => {
    const [food, setFood] = useState({});
    const apik = process.env.REACT_APP_FOOD_API_KEY;
    const foodUrl = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?number=1&apiKey=${apik}`;

    useEffect(() => {
        urlFetch();
    },[]);

    const urlFetch = () => {
        fetch(foodUrl)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                }
                throw res;
            })
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json.recipes[0].image);
                setFood(json);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log("something went wrong...", err));
    };

    const handleYah = () => {
        userFood.push(food.recipes[0].image);
    };
    console.log(userFood);

    return (
        <div className="home">

            {Object.keys(food).length ? (
                <img src={food.recipes[0].image} alt="Random Food" className="home__img" />
            ) : (
                "no images"
            )}
            <div className="home__buttons--container">
                <button className="home__yesno" id="home__nah" onClick={() => urlFetch()}>Nah</button>
                <Link
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/Checkout",
                        state: { userFood },
                    }}
                >
                    <button id="home__checkout">Checkout</button>
                </Link>
                <button className="home__yesno" id="home__yah" onClick={() => urlFetch() & handleYah()}>Yah</button>


            </div>
        </div >
    );
};

export default Home;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Checkout.css";


const testBotFood = [
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661365-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715544-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716279-556x370.jpg",
    "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/645978-556x370.jpg",
];

const Checkout = () => {
    let location = useLocation()
    console.log(location)
    // let userFoodCopy = location.state.userFood
    // console.log(userFoodCopy)
    // function arrayMatch(userFoodCopy, testBotFood) {
    //     const matchFood = [];
    //     for (let i = 0; i < userFoodCopy.length; i++) {
    //         for (let j = 0; j < testBotFood.length; j++) {
    //             if (userFoodCopy[i] === testBotFood[j]) {
    //                 matchFood.push(userFoodCopy[i]);
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    //     return matchFood;
    // }
    // const arrayOfMatches = arrayMatch(userFoodCopy, testBotFood);


    // function arrayNotMatch(userFoodCopy, testBotFood) {
    //     const noMatchFood = [];
    //     for (let i = 0; i < userFoodCopy.length; i++) {
    //         for (let j = 0; j < testBotFood.length; j++) {
    //             if (
    //                 userFoodCopy[i] !== testBotFood[j] &&
    //                 !noMatchFood.includes(userFoodCopy[i])
    //             ) {
    //                 noMatchFood.push(userFoodCopy[i]);
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    //     return noMatchFood;
    // }
    // //   console.log(arrayNotMatch(userFoodCopy, testBotFood));

    // return (
    //     <div className="checkout">
    //         {/* <nav>
    //           <Link to="/" style={{textDecoration:"none"}}>
    //             <button className="headerButton" id="backButton">
    //               &#9665;
    //             </button>
    //           </Link>
    //         </nav> */}
    //         <h2>Match</h2>
    //         <div className="checkout__checkMatch">
    //             {arrayOfMatches.map((copyFood) => (
    //                 <div className="checkout__images--grid">
    //                     {/* <Link
    //               to={{
    //                 pathname: "/Messages",
    //                 state: { arrayOfMatches },
    //               }}
    //               key={copyFood}
    //             > */}
    //                     <img
    //                         src={copyFood}
    //                         alt="userPics"
    //                         key={copyFood}
    //                         className="checkout__images"
    //                     />
    //                     {/* </Link> */}
    //                 </div>
    //             ))}
    //         </div>
    //         <h2>Favorites</h2>
    //         <div className="checkout__checkMatch">
    //             {arrayNotMatch(userFoodCopy, testBotFood).map((noMatch) => (
    //                 <div className="checkout__images--grid" >
    //                     <img src={noMatch} alt="userPics" key={noMatch} className="checkout__images" />
    //                 </div>
    //             ))}
    //         </div>
    //     </div>
    // );
};

export default Checkout;
```

Here is the app root level

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './components/Header/Header.jsx';
// import Menu from './components/Menu/Menu.jsx';
import Home from './components/Home/Home.jsx';
import Checkout from './components/Checkout/Checkout.jsx'


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />

      <Routes>
        {/* <Route exact path="/Menu" element={<Menu />} /> */}
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path='/Checkout' element={<Checkout />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think the index.js is coded correctly, but I'll paste it just in case

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Any suggestions would be great! I feel like it's a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

And thank you, Som Shekhar Mukherjee. I should've done so in the beginning. Here is the github pages link https://hongssam9.github.io/Lood/
For some reason, it doesn't take me straight to the homepage.

Comment: Create a minimal reproducible example for others to debug, make your code runnable here on SO or share a link to codesandbox. It's very hard to debug like this.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I posted the link on the post.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this.I found the answer in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8246). Turns out the state is now passed directly as a prop, and not as an attribute of the to prop.
In your code,change this line.

```
<Link to={{
           pathname: "/Checkout",
           state: { userFood },
         }}
>
```

To:

```
<Link
      to={{
      pathname: "/Checkout",              
      }}
      state= { userFood }
 >
```

I hope you got my point.Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I did the workaround below and it seems to work, but compromising the code. I hope for a better satisfactory solution.

```
import CadastrosView from "../views/CadastrosView";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

var entidade: any;
var ent: string;

const PagesPromotionForm = () => {  
//    const entidade = useLocation().state.tabela; // isso não dá certo   
    entidade = useLocation().state;    

    if (entidade != null) { ent = entidade.tabela }
    return (
            <CadastrosView tabela={ ent as string }/>    
    )        
}

export default PagesPromotionForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most of your code in Checkout.js dependent on UserFoodCopy array which is not getting fecthed from `useLocation()`.

This can be solved by changing `let userFoodCopy = location.state.userFood;` to `let userFoodCopy = location.state;`

And I guess once you get the userFoodCopy, you can check all the below functions in `Checkout.js`.

You can also take reference from this [article](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-router-passing-data-states-through-links/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20data%20passed,state%3B%20console.)

Comment: I have tried that. I wanted to check location first by console.log(location) to see if state is available, but state is coming up null, which prevent me from accessing any data that comes from the Home component.